# How can I write into SSL security pop up pin code with Selenium WebDriver by JAVA?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I'm trying to write in JAVA some function that can write pin into SSL security pop-up for my automation test. Unfortunately I still don't find solutions. This is an element that Selenium doesn't see. Could anybody help me please?

[image]

Comment: What kind of pop-up is it?
The picture you provided is not providing essential information.
Can you share the link / page you are working on?

Comment: What kind of help you want to get if you provide only some form screenshot without html code and do not show any efforts from your side?

Comment: I doubt this is possible because what you see is a dialog that doesn't come from the browser. Use a different certificate or silence that dialog somehow.

Comment: This is an external pop-up of security before an entrance to site. Selenium doesn't see this. I have tried to deal with actions and some robot example that I have found.

Comment: Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.click().perform();
        action.sendKeys("my pin").build().perform();
        action.keyDown(Keys.ENTER).perform();

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);

Comment: @Eliyahu  Unfortunately this is a closed environment and I can't give URL.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can click on web elements in Chrome or WPF elements inside windows applications. The pop up is neither one of them.

You can use the Robot object to type to the keyboard, but you have no way to know when this pop up appears or not. Unless this pop up shows at the exact same time everyday.

Comment: I tried to solve with Robot, but it didn't work. I have found an option with autoIT and it works well.